# VBA copying from Excel file to WORD file bookmark

Tags: vba

When I copy a chart from Excel ('Report' sheet) to a WORD file ('Report template.docx'), why does VBA wipe out the previous content of the WORD file? I suspect the problem is in line 'wddoc.Range.Paste' but I don't know how to change it to avoid the problem.

Sub ActivateWordTransferData()

```
Dim wdapp As Object, wddoc As Object
Dim strdocname As String

Set wdapp = GetObject(, "Word.Application")
wdapp.Visible = True

strdocname = "C:\users\ian\Documents\Dropbox\Report template.docx"
Set wddoc = wdapp.documents(strdocname)

Worksheets("Report").Shapes("Chart 2").Copy
wdapp.Activate
wddoc.bookmarks("bkmark4").Select
wddoc.Range.Paste

wddoc.Save
Set wddoc = Nothing
Set wdapp = Nothing
Application.CutCopyMode = False
```

End Sub

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure why the contents of the Word document are being overwritten.

However, removing the .Select operation and just pasting into the bookmark's range seems to work.

Remove these lines:

```
wddoc.bookmarks("bkmark4").Select
wddoc.Range.Paste
```

and replace with this line:

```
wddoc.bookmarks("bkmark4").Range.Paste
```